# TFS API - Fetch latest two checkins for each file

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm trying to fetch changeset metadata on the two most recent checkins for each of about 1000 files. The challenge is trying to do this in a reasonably efficient way.

Consider this overload of `VersionControlServer.QueryHistory` :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff736442(v=vs.100).aspx#

From observed behaviour, it seems that when `sortAscending = false`, that the result seems to be received in descending order of changeset id. If this was true, then I could call the method, setting `maxCount = 2` for each file. This would get me meta data about the two most recent checkins for a file. (using `maxCount = 0`, and sorting the changesets on the client side may cause a lot of data to be pulled).

My question is, is my assumption about the sort order when `maxCount = 2` and `sortAscending = false` safe to make ? The documentation says that when `sortAscending = true`, then it is sorted in ascending order, but when `sortAscending = false`, it's not so clear what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use this method before, but according to [this blog](https://paulselles.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/team-foundation-server-api-programmatically-downloading-files-from-source-control/), blogger wanted to sort descending, then he made `sortAscending = false`:

```
// We want to sort descending
queryHistoryParameters.SortAscending = false;
```